# Triage and identification for an orphanned plant

Tags: identification

I found this plant outdoors by a trash can, and decided to take it home. I didn't notice any infestation on it, and cleared off the yellow/brownish leaves (somewhat soggy) that I found on it. My questions - one - what is it? and two - can it be saved?

[image: an orphaned plant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a type of Aglaonema the exact variety alludes me. Yes, it can be easily saved, if the leaves were yellow and soggy, it was probably just overwatered. If it is to wet dry it out completely, and then water it according to the species care instructions. Late you might try to take cuttings and rooting them either in water or soil according to care instructions to have it be less lanky. Leave the stumps, because they might sprout.